# What are conditions to unlock artifacts sets in Archive?

Tags: genshin-impact

What are conditions to unlock artifacts sets in Archive? I'm talking about this page:

[image]

Do I need to collect all 5 in my inventory? Or do I need to just pickup them at least once? I'm asking because I want to spend my 3* and 4* artifacts to level up my 5*, but some of them are from not yet completed sets.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I noticed this from my 3* Gambler Set that i used up earlier, You only need to collect them once.

for example: if you previously collected a feather artifact and used it to levelling-up another artifact and then you get the other 4 artifact types from the same set and same rank in the future, it will show you the artifact set from the archive because you completed collecting 5 artifact from each different type within the same set and same rank.